# 'working, please wait' screen with thread?

Tags: delphi, multithreading, adsi

Perhaps, it is very easy for you, but I am hard working on a project (for educational purposes) that is querying adsi with TADSISearch component, for several days. I'm trying to show a 'Working, Please wait..' splash screen with a man worker animated gif on Form2 while TADSISearch is searching the Active Directory. Although i tried every possibilities according to me, but i couldn't succeed. I tried to use TADSISearch in a thread, but thread is terminating before ADSIsearch finishes. I think TADSISearch is not thread safe. What do you think? Also, another way that I created Form2 and used a thread for updating it but the animated gif is stopping while main form gone adsi searching. What can you say about these? How can i make a please wait screen while ADSISearch is working and keep main form responding. Application.ProcessMessages or timer is not a way too. Thanks a lot for reading and answers.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using on your thread? It's seems unlikely that the thread is ending before TADSISearch ends, that would only happen if the component worked itself in its own thread which does not seems to be the case.

Comment: As Jorge says we need to see your code, my guess is that you are not really running the active directory search in a thread (do you have freeonterminate set to true?) or are trying to access the mainform directly (without synchronize) from the thread. Can't say more until we've seen your code.

Comment: please wait for Monday, thank you all for your interest..

Comment: I've discovered that, when i use ADSISearch in a thread, it gives error: Unable to bind LDAP://xxx. Outside, it runs perfect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The graphical user interface should be  updated by the main thread. You should put your search code into a separate thread, and while the searcher thread is working, your main thread can show the animation along with "Please wait" message.

Your searcher thread can notify the main thread when search is done by any of the available synchronization techniques. The simplest one is to define a method in your thread class which stops the animation in user interface, and pass that method to Synchronize at the end of Execute method of your searcher thread.

Your searcher thread code will be something like this:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure NotifyEndOfThread;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

uses MainFormUnit;

procedure TMyThread.NotifyEndOfThread;
begin
  MainForm.ShowAnimation := False;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    {Add your search code here}
  finally
    Synchronize(NotifyEndOfThread);
  end;
end;
```

And your main thread's code will be like this:

```
TMainForm = class(TForm)
...
private 
  FShowAnimation : Boolean;
  procedure SetShowAnimation(Value: Boolean);
public
  property ShowAnimation : Boolean read FShowAnimation write SetShowAnimation;
end;

procedure TMainForm.SetShowAnimation(Value: Boolean);
begin
  FShowAnimation := Value;
  if FShowAnimation then
    {Add animation code here}
  else
    {Stop animation}
end;
```

Comment: You can add your ADSISearch code in Execute method where I mentioned; "{Add your search code here}". Of course I haven't used TADSISearch component you mentioned in your post, and I don't know how exactly it works.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this:

**Threaded Splashscreen for Delphi**
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/20139

I use this on a touchscreen/terminal application (thin client, Wifi, RemObjects, etc) and it works nice!
Also got an animated gif working.

Answer (score 1):

How can the thread terminate before the search is finished? If the search is executed in the thread and you have only one instance of the thread it should work.

Comment: I don't know, i am asking that already. Perhaps, because of TADSISearch component's being not thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just do a

```
f := TMyWaitForm.Create(self);
try
   f.Show();
   ...start the TADSISearch...
finally
   FreeAndNil(f);
end;
```

Putting an animated GIF on the TMyWaitForm (which displays itself) ?

I have a progress form when building websites in my web creation program, and this works like a charm.

You even may consider showing some state information on the wait form (if the TADSISearch component/software has a call back function or event which can be assigned).

Displaying a running clock showing the amount of time the process is taking, is also a nice touch.

Comment: He can't. As the TADSISearch is performing the search in the main thread, the main message loop is not processing messages so the gif would not update (nor any other kind of user interface updates).

Comment: I also tried using TADSISearch component in a thread that's doing synchronize to update animated gif's form (Form2) as:

TMyThread.Execute;
var
   ADSISearch: TADSISearch;
begin
   ADSISearch stuff...
   Synchronize(doUpdate);
end;

TMyThread.doUpdate;
begin
   Form2.Update;
end;