# How to open ClientDataSet (master/detail) in separate thread(different of main thread)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firebird, datasnap, dbexpress

Using: Delphi XE2, DBExpress, Firebird

I can't access any VCL control outside the main thread safely, that includes forms, panels, edits, etc and the Timage and Timage descendants. I'm need to open ClientDataSet (Master/Detail) in separate Thread(different of main thread).

I'm need to create animated splash screen while accessing database

Can someone show me a simple example of how to do this?

Comment: See [Create animated splashscreen delphi 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8188924/576719) and ['working, please wait' screen with thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2077930/576719).

Comment: Thanks LI RD but im lookin for example with ClientDaSet in the same form.

Comment: Using this codes, my Animated Gif was freezed

Comment: excuse me for poor english

Comment: I'll post an example tomorrow. Meanwhile, happy new year!

Comment: ok, thank you!! happy new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm assuming that the database access in a thread is of no problem for you.</strike>

For a complete example of a threaded access to a dbExpress database (including feedback to the main thread), see the examples made by [Marco Cantù](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45145/marco-cantu) here: [dbexpress_firebird_examples](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/dbexpress_firebird_examples.html).

It involves putting all the database connection setup in a `TDataModule` and creating an instance of this datamodule for each threaded access.

Anyway,
to make the GUI informed about the background thread process with an animated Gif, here is an example:

[image]

```
unit TestAnimatedScreen;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TMyEndNotify = procedure (value: Boolean) of object;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fEndNotification : TMyEndNotify;
    procedure NotifyEndOfThread;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    Constructor Create(endNotification : TMyEndNotify);
  end;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FShowAnimation : Boolean;
    procedure SetShowAnimation(value : Boolean);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    property ShowAnimation : Boolean read FShowAnimation write SetShowAnimation;
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyThread.NotifyEndOfThread;
begin
  if Assigned(fEndNotification) then
    fEndNotification(False);
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(endNotification: TMyEndNotify);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fEndNotification := endNotification;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := True; // Free automatically
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    {Add your database access code here}
    Sleep(5000); // Simulate lengthy process
  finally
    Synchronize(NotifyEndOfThread);
  end;
end;

{ TMainForm }

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowAnimation := True;
  TMyThread.Create(Self.SetShowAnimation);
end;

procedure TMainForm.SetShowAnimation(value: Boolean);
begin
  FShowAnimation := Value;
  if FShowAnimation then
  begin
    {Add animation code here}
    Button1.Enabled := false;
    Button1.Caption := 'Processing, please wait ...';
    (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).AnimateLoop := glEnabled;
    (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := true;
  end
  else
  begin
    {Stop animation}
    (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := false;
    Button1.Caption := 'Start lengthy process';
    Button1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

end.
```

---

```
object MainForm: TMainForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'MainForm'
  ClientHeight = 265
  ClientWidth = 236
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Image1: TImage
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 200
    Height = 200
    AutoSize = True
    IncrementalDisplay = True
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 224
    Width = 200
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Start lengthy process'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Should you have an older Delphi version than Delphi 2007, see [How to use Animated Gif in a delphi form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573572/576719) for more information about how to implement an animated GIF.

The animated GIF I used can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format).

Comment: but the database access in a thread is a problem for me. when im try to use i, have access violation

Comment: OK, then I suggest you edit your question and add the code for database access plus a good description of the error.

Comment: Normally a `TClientDataSet` should be local to the thread. And remember to open a new database session from the thread as well. If you want to transfer data from the thread clientdataset to something in the main thread, do that in the `Synchronize()` method.

Comment: OK. I am reproducing the error in a small app to show you. Later post here.

Comment: [Marco Cantu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/45145/marco-cantu) has published some examples for `Firebird` and `dbExpress`, including a multi-threaded pooling example. See [`dbexpress_firebird_examples`](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/dbexpress_firebird_examples.html).